# PHP how to check if variable is not 3 different numbers

Tags: php

I would like to check if variable is not 3 different numbers (ids), and if not one or other to display information.

For example :

```
if ($cat_id !== 151 || $cat_id !== 154 || $cat_id !== 160) { 

echo 'something';
```

Comment: `!($cat_id === 151 || $cat_id === 154 || $cat_id === 160)` or `$cat_id !== 151 && $cat_id !== 154 && $cat_id !== 160` or `!in_array($cat_id, [151, 154, 160], true)` ... im pretty sure there are more ways.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: The duplicate talks about using strings, but for numbers it's exactly the same process.

Answer (score 0):

Fast and in my opinion easy to read solution:

```
if (!in_array($cat_id, [151,154,160], true))
{
    echo "Something";
}
```

Edit: The third parameter i pass to `in_array` (`true`) means "strict type checking" if your $cat_id is not always an integer, you can also set this to `false` but i recommend to leave it on strict.

Comment: Thank you this is what i was looking for. Thanks for the help